# Count notification from Firebase notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, listener, badge

I want to **count notification** when received before make **Shortcut Badge** on my app icon. Now, I can make Shortcut Badge and create php file for send notification from Server sucessful.

But I have a problem **I can't count notification** for show number by Shortcut Badge.

I will try NotificationListenerService or StatusBarNotification 
but I don't know where to call file and work flow.

Help me please.

[image]

This is my workflow
[image]

Comment: you need to store all notification when it receives  from firebase

Comment: no i just count unread notification

Comment: yes, but you need to store somewhere notification for display unread count

Comment: Ahhh... yes but you know?  how to store and count notificaions

Comment: when you receive notification in firebase listener then store it in SQLite DB
then set read count as "N"  and while displaying badge count get all "N" status and update status as "Y"

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will try ;)